# Does my UK visit - business (academic) - 6 months refusal will affect the Student general visa for UK?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, student-visas

I have got a refusal for my UK visit - business (academic) - 6 months visa in March-2016. Now I am planning to apply for the Tier-4 General student visa. Does the refusal affect my student visa application?
I will be going to apply in Nov-2020. Any valuable suggestions.

And also in the decision, the 2nd point that they have mentioned circumstances in Bangladesh but I was working and living in India. Later form December-2016 I am working in the middle east for the past 4 years.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

UK Immigration have refused you under section V, 3.6, for submitting a fraudulent document. Since you've been refused for deception you can expect a ten year ban, starting from the date of the refusal above, if you apply again.

You have exactly zero chance of being granted a UK visit visa of any type until 2026, and unless your circumstances change radically before then, you will almost certainly be refused again.

Forget about visiting the UK in the near future. Find somewhere else to continue your studies.

Comment: Dear Arthur, Thank you for your reply. May I know what the circumstances that can help in applying for my student tier 4 visa. Thank you.

Comment: @NMadhusudhana I don't think I can be any clearer - you will be banned for ten years. You will NOT get a visa until at least 2026. If you're determined to press on with this you will need advice from a specialist immigration lawyer in the UK.

Comment: What are the chances if I go with a specialist immigration lawyer in my case?

Comment: @NMadhusudhana You'd have to ask them that. That's why you consult them.